# i get multiple error after replacing my old sql code to pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

following is my sql code

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
$user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$pageID = '33'; // The ID of the page, the article or the video ...

//function to calculate the percent
function percent($num_amount, $num_total) {
    $count1 = $num_amount / $num_total;
    $count2 = $count1 * 100;
    $count = number_format($count2, 0);
    return $count;
}

// check if the user has already clicked on the unlike (rate = 2) or the like (rate = 1)
$dislike_sql = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  wcd_yt_rate WHERE ip = "'.$user_ip.'" and id_item = "'.$pageID.'" and rate = 2 ');
$dislike_count = mysql_result($dislike_sql, 0);

$like_sql = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  wcd_yt_rate WHERE ip = "'.$user_ip.'" and id_item = "'.$pageID.'" and rate = 1 ');
$like_count = mysql_result($like_sql, 0);

// count all the rate 
$rate_all_count = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  wcd_yt_rate WHERE id_item = "'.$pageID.'"');
$rate_all_count = mysql_result($rate_all_count, 0);

$rate_like_count = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  wcd_yt_rate WHERE id_item = "'.$pageID.'" and rate = 1');
$rate_like_count = mysql_result($rate_like_count, 0);
$rate_like_percent = percent($rate_like_count, $rate_all_count);

$rate_dislike_count = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  wcd_yt_rate WHERE id_item = "'.$pageID.'" and rate = 2');
$rate_dislike_count = mysql_result($rate_dislike_count, 0);
$rate_dislike_percent = percent($rate_dislike_count, $rate_all_count);
?>
```

I tried to replace this code with following code but i get multiple error

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
$user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$pageID = '33'; // The ID of the page, the article or the video ...
//function to calculate the percent
function percent($num_amount, $num_total) {
    $count1 = $num_amount / $num_total;
    $count2 = $count1 * 100;
    $count = number_format($count2, 0);
    return $count;
}
// check if the user has already clicked on the unlike (rate = 2) or the like (rate = 1)
$dislike_sql = $db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  wcd_yt_rate WHERE ip = "'.$user_ip.'" and id_item = "'.$pageID.'" and rate = 2 ');
$dislike_count = $db->query($dislike_sql, 0);
$like_sql = $db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  wcd_yt_rate WHERE ip = "'.$user_ip.'" and id_item = "'.$pageID.'" and rate = 1 ');
$like_count = $db->query($like_sql, 0);
// count all the rate 
$rate_all_count = $db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  wcd_yt_rate WHERE id_item = "'.$pageID.'"');
$rate_all_count = $db->query($rate_all_count, 0);
$rate_like_count = $db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  wcd_yt_rate WHERE id_item = "'.$pageID.'" and rate = 1');
$rate_like_count = $db->query($rate_like_count, 0);
$rate_like_percent = percent($rate_like_count, $rate_all_count);
$rate_dislike_count = $db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  wcd_yt_rate WHERE id_item = "'.$pageID.'" and rate = 2');
$rate_dislike_count = $db->query($rate_dislike_count, 0);
$rate_dislike_percent = percent($rate_dislike_count, $rate_all_count);
?>
```

ERROR in my code `Warning: PDO::query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given line 32, 34,37,39`

**EDITED CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>WebCodo :: Like & Dislike System With jQuery Ajax and PHP</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="webcodo-top" >
            <a href="http://webcodo.com/like-dislike-system-with-jquery-ajax-and-php-youtube-like-design">
                <div class="wcd wcd-tuto"> < Come back to the tuto page</div>
            </a>
            <a href="http://webcodo.com">
                <div class="wcd wcd-logo">WEBCODO</div>
            </a>
            <div class="wcd"></div>
        </div>
        <?php
        include 'config.php';
        $user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $pageID = '33'; // The ID of the page, the article or the video ...
        //function to calculate the percent

        function percent($num_amount, $num_total) {
            $count1 = $num_amount / $num_total;
            $count2 = $count1 * 100;
            $count = number_format($count2, 0);
            return $count;
        }

        // check if the user has already clicked on the unlike (rate = 2) or the like (rate = 1)
        $dislike_stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  wcd_yt_rate WHERE ip = :user_ip and id_item = :item_id and rate = 2;');
        $dislike_stmt->execute(array(':user_ip' => $user_ip, ':item_id' => $pageID));
        $dislike_count = $dislike_stmt->fetchColumn();

        $like_sql = $db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  wcd_yt_rate WHERE ip =:user_ip and id_item =:item_id and rate = 1 ');
        $like_sql->execute(array(':user_ip' => $user_ip, ':item_id' => $pageID));
        $like_count = $like_sql->fetchColumn();

        // count all the rate 

        $rate_all_count = $db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  wcd_yt_rate WHERE id_item =:item_id');
        $rate_all_count->execute(array(':item_id' => $pageID));
        $rate_all_count = $rate_all_count->fetchColumn();

        $rate_like_count = $db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  wcd_yt_rate WHERE id_item =:item_id and rate = 1');
        $rate_like_count->execute(array(':item_id' => $pageID));
        $rate_like_percent = $rate_like_count->fetchColumn();

        $rate_dislike_count = $db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  wcd_yt_rate WHERE id_item =:item_id and rate = 2');
        $rate_dislike_count->execute(array(':item_id' => $pageID));
        $rate_dislike_percent = $rate_dislike_count->fetchColumn();

        $rate_dislike_percent = percent($rate_dislike_count, $rate_all_count);
        ?>

        <script>
            $(function () {
                var pageID = <?php echo $pageID; ?>;

                $('.like-btn').click(function () {
                    $('.dislike-btn').removeClass('dislike-h');
                    $(this).addClass('like-h');
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "ajax.php",
                        data: 'act=like&pageID=' + pageID,
                        success: function () {
                        }
                    });
                });
                $('.dislike-btn').click(function () {
                    $('.like-btn').removeClass('like-h');
                    $(this).addClass('dislike-h');
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "ajax.php",
                        data: 'act=dislike&pageID=' + pageID,
                        success: function () {
                        }
                    });
                });
                $('.share-btn').click(function () {
                    $('.share-cnt').toggle();
                });
            });
        </script>
        <div class="tab-cnt">
            <h1>Youtube Like & Dislike System With PHP, jQuery & Ajax</h1>
            <div class="tab-tr" id="t1">
                <div class="like-btn <?php
                if ($like_count == 1) {
                    echo 'like-h';
                }
                ?>">Like</div>
                <div class="dislike-btn <?php
                if ($dislike_count == 1) {
                    echo 'dislike-h';
                }
                ?>"></div>

                <div class="share-btn">Share</div>
                <div class="stat-cnt">
                    <div class="rate-count"><?php echo $rate_all_count; ?></div>
                    <div class="stat-bar">
                        <div class="bg-green" style="width:<?php echo $rate_like_percent; ?>%;"></div>
                        <div class="bg-red" style="width:<?php echo $rate_dislike_percent; ?>%"></div>
                    </div><!-- stat-bar -->
                    <div class="dislike-count"><?php echo $rate_dislike_count; ?></div>
                    <div class="like-count"><?php echo $rate_like_count; ?></div>
                </div><!-- /stat-cnt -->
            </div><!-- /tab-tr -->
            <div class="share-cnt">
                <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
                <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
                    <a class="addthis_button_linkedin_counter"></a>
                    <a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a>
                    <a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a>
                    <a class="addthis_button_google_plusone" g:plusone:size="medium"></a> 
                    <a class="addthis_button_pinterest_pinit"></a>
                    <a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style"></a>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /share-cnt -->
        </div><!-- /tuto-cnt -->
    </body>
</html>
```

**after above edit i get following error**

```
Notice: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to int in C:\Users\sanoj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\like youtube\index.php on line 26
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0020  254504  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0260  291496  percent( )  ..\index.php:50

( ! ) Warning: Division by zero in C:\Users\sanoj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\like youtube\index.php on line 26
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0020  254504  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0260  291496  percent( )  ..\index.php:50

( ! ) Notice: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to int in C:\Users\sanoj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\like youtube\index.php on line 26
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0020  254504  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0370  295088  percent( )  ..\index.php:55

( ! ) Warning: Division by zero in C:\Users\sanoj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\like youtube\index.php on line 26
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0020  254504  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0370  295088  percent( )  ..\index.php:55
```

Comment: @AlirezaMirzaeiyan `Warning: PDO::query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given line 32, 34,37,39`

Comment: Two suggestions for better question-writing. (1) Edit your when someone asks for more information in a comment.  (2) Try to provide short examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using prepared statements is not the same as using plain SQL queries. Please, refer to [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) about this. There are good examples how to use prepared statements and binding parameters. For instance, retrieving dislikes count should look like this:

```
$dislike_stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  wcd_yt_rate WHERE ip = :user_ip and id_item = :item_id and rate = 2;');
$dislike_stmt->execute(array(':user_ip' => $user_ip, ':item_id' => $pageID));
$dislike_count = $dislike_stmt->fetchColumn();
```

Using binding parameters also would allow you avoiding SQL injection threats.

Comment: $dislike_count doesn't contain the same value as it did with the old code. To get the same you have to use [fetchColumn](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#fetchcolumn) instead of fetch()

Comment: `$rate_all_count = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  wcd_yt_rate WHERE id_item = "' . $pageID . '"');
        $rate_all_count = mysql_result($rate_all_count, 0);` am confused about this`

Comment: What's wrong with it? How is it different from other queries?

Comment: i get error here `Notice: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to int in C:\Users\sanoj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\like system\index.php on line 26`

Comment: @sanoj I guess you haven't fetched the result from the executed statement with `fetchColumn ()` function.

Comment: i executed statement with fetchColumn () but still i get

Comment: @sanojlawrence Could you please provide full code that you wrote for it?

Comment: I  see. Try to rename `$rate_all_count` with smth. else. For example, `$rate_all_count_result = $rate_all_count->fetchColumn();`. It's not a good idea using the same variable for different purposes in the same scope.

Comment: @sanojlawrence as I supposed, the error is not due to PDO. It's in percent calculation: `$rate_dislike_percent = percent($rate_dislike_count, $rate_all_count);`. You haven't replaced variables with new names and passed there PDOStatement object instead of count value. Please, check carefully your code.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `$stmt = $db->prepare()`, then calling `query($stmt,...)` with the PreparedStatement object. That's wrong in PDO.

You need to call the `$stmt->execute()` method on each PreparedStatement object. Read this for an explanation and example.  http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Then when you've called `$stmt->execute()`, you need to call `$stmt->fetch()` to retrieve the results. Notice that your `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...` queries all return one row with one column in it, so you need to call `$stmt->fetch()` just for those queries. Read this, especially Example 3. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

A valid shortcut to getting just one column from the row is `$stmt->fetchColumn(0)` . Read this. http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php  But be careful not to use this call just once for multiple-row result sets, or you may leave a partially unfetched resultset in your `$stmt`. Read this.  http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.closecursor.php